# Stay Logged in in Facebook?

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser, ionic-framework

I connected Facebook login with my android app (Cordova + Ionic Framework) successfully using **inAppBrowser** .. My problem now is that how can I make the user log in just once then the next time they open the app they get automatically connected without the need to login again?

I saw a question similar like mine but it's in ASP.NET and the answer to that question was A) "use localstorage to save credentials. But bad idea. Cause localstorage life cycle isn't good enough. Specially iPhone treats localstorage as temporary storage"
B) "use database like webSql to save the credentials in your app"... blah3x

Are the suggestions above for ASP.NET also works with Cordova? Or there's another (better) way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the user token. This token usually lasts 1 month or so, with this token you can keep things going without asking for login again.